# Centering fixed divs within floating divs

Tags: css

See my example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ewrjh

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="box-container"></div>
<div id="box">test</div>
<div id="box">test</div>
<div id="box">test</div>
<div id="box">test</div>
</div>

#container {width:100%;}

#box-container{width:800px;float:left;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;}

#box {width:180px;margin: 2%;float:left;text-align:center;border:1px solid #ccc; display: inline-block;}
```

I want to center the 4 divs 'box' in the center of the percentage div 'container'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For one you shouldn't be using multiple id's called box on the same page.

Comment: You have to make `#box` a child of `#container`. And also, as Phorden said, you can't use multiple ids. They should be unique.

Comment: You have an extra closing div tag also.

Comment: You can't re-use IDs. Try changing it to a class and making sure the `box` divs are actually inside the `box-container` div which, at the time of commenting...they aren't. Oh and either float them or use `inline-block`...not both.

Comment: @phorden tell him to use class instead of id for multiple instances to be helpful.

Comment: Like this, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxnrl?

Comment: @MennoGouw He wasn't very specific on what he wanted. I was just pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Gosh I feel dumb, I didn't realize that the box was outside of the container div. With that said,  I corrected it and it still doesn't work. I want the 4 'box' to be centered in the page. Also- while arguably bad in practice, I've used multiple ids instead of classes on many sites, without any problems.

Comment: @phorden The obvious for you, that is what this site has to many, people with tunnel-vision, really no personal offense meant. But think like this, if he does something wrong don't just say it is wrong since he clearly does not know how to do it right. Just tell him how he does it right so next time you do not have to spend time on "the obvious".

Comment: Thanks @MennoGouw for sticking up for me :)

Comment: Your welcome, just find it strange that on a site that should help people unconstructive comments get voted up. It happens a lot because advanced people cannot seem to place themselves into beginners minds.

Comment: Thanks. And as I mentioned- I have been using multiple IDs on pages (including some larger sites) without any problems.

Comment: @MennoGouw I was not trying to be mean. I was simply stating something that could be fixed that was obvious to me. I wasn't sure what he was asking for exactly. Unfortunately the question could have been worded better.

Comment: @phorden i am just saying that telling a person he does things wrong does not help anyone. If a comment is not helpfull or adding to discussion then do not post. By just adding "use class instead if id for multiple instances" the comment gets vallue.

Comment: @user3220251 yeah but it is not proper coding. W3c validation will give errors and future browsers might give errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your code and provided a new sample here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdLAw

I mostly removed cruft, and simplified your css selector:

```
.box {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The best method to achieve centering is using the margin property.  Apply this to your div element add add some vertical spacing, and you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I want all 4 box divs to be in one row- centered in the page (which has a 100% width)